# Natural deduction - help solving

Tags: natural-deduction

I have this issue in natural deduction:

B -> (A & ~A) ├ ~B

I am having a really hard time understanding the rules in natural deduction - but this is what I got so far - can someone help me to the end?

1. B / premis
2. (A&~A) /premis
3. B-> ^ /1, 2  ^E
4. B /1
5. ^ /3->E
6. ~B /4,5 ->I

Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what rules of deduction you have at your disposal. If you have [modus tollens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_tollens) that would probably be the simplest. You would need to establish both $B \Rightarrow A$ and $\neg A$, from which you can conclude $\neg B$.

Comment: Thank you for your help kccu

Comment: I have tried again in the question - still not sure if it is right.. It is a new subject to me :)

Answer (score 1):

For a start, neither (1) nor (2) are given to you as premisses. Your premiss is the given conditional, and then your proof should proceed by assuming $B$ for reductio ...

To be honest, your proof attempt suggests you really haven't understood ND at all. For a gentle and I hope very accessible intro to ND (which is quite freely available) try the relevant chapters of my book *Introduction to Formal Logic* which you can download from https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl

Answer (score 0):

Natural Deduction's rules of inference revolve around 'introducing' or 'eliminating' logical connectives.   So that is where we start.$\def\fitch#1#2{~~~~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}$

You are given a premise $B\to(A\land\lnot A)$ and wish to infer $\lnot B$.   Well there is a conditional and conjunction to eliminate in the premise, and a negation to introduce in the conclusion. Clearly these rules need to be understood (at least).

$$\dfrac{\phi\to\chi\quad\phi}{\chi}{~\small{\to}\mathsf e}\qquad\dfrac{\gamma\wedge\beta}{\gamma}{~\small{\land}\mathsf e}\qquad\dfrac{\gamma\wedge\beta}{\beta}{~\small{\land}\mathsf e}\qquad\dfrac{[\psi]\\~\vdots\\\bot}{\lnot\psi~}
{~\small\lnot\mathsf i}$$

So... to successfully apply *negation introduction*, an assumption must be made, under which a contradiction must be derived.   For this proof that assumption must be $B$, and this and the premise then allows *conditional elimination* to be applied, thus deriving $A\land\lnot A$.   Then from this... well...

$$\fitch{~~1.~~B\to(A\land\lnot A)\hspace{7ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~2.~~B\hspace{16ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{~~3.~~A\land\lnot A\hspace{10ex}{\to}\mathsf e~1,2\\~~4.~~A\hspace{16ex}{\land}\mathsf e~3\\~~5.~~\lnot A\hspace{14.5ex}{\land}\mathsf e~3\\~~~~\vdots\\~~\mathrm m.~~\bot}\\~~\mathrm n.~~\lnot B\hspace{17ex}\lnot\mathsf i~2{-}\mathrm m}$$

So all that is left is to derive that contradiction.